# SVN Merge Combination

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

Recently, I encountered problems on merging the my code with my colleague's code. Here is the story.

1) Firstly, I am on my own to develop my project. After that one colleague joined the development.

2) I then used my developing code as trunk code, and upload to the svn trunk folder like so.

```
/svn/proj
/svn/proj/trunk/ (my trunk code here)
```

3) I then svn mkdir to make 2 branches like so

```
/svn/proj  
/svn/proj/trunk/ (my trunk code here)  
/svn/proj/branches/peter/(my branch)  
/svn/proj/branches/paul/(my colleague's branch)
```

4) I then tell my colleague to checkout the trunk's code and use those code as the base of his branch to keep on development. At the same time, I also use the same trunk to keep on my development.

Here is the question

Both of us use tortoise svn to do the whole check in /out and all sorts of svn process, after some time, his code has been modified and so as mine. One day we try to merge both of our codes together (after some milestone changes have been done), but we face the following problems.

1) Since my colleague and I are not interfere with each other (i.e. I don't modify his code and vice versa). I want to combine both my code and his code to one, but I can't seem to find anything similar to this in the merge option. How can we achieve this in tortoise SVN?

2) My concept on the merge process is as follows

1. First I merge my latest branch back to trunk and commit the changes
2. Then I tell my colleague to merge his code to the trunk
3. He will encounter conflicts, I need to sit down and solve with him
4. Finally we commit the changes (with all conflicts solved)

We again use the newly committed trunk as our branch base to continue our development, the process repeats and continues.

Since step 3 requires significant time to perform, is there anyway to make the whole process more efficiently?

Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 0):

**Side-notes**

If you use pre-1.8 SVN, it's good time to update to it *in any case*

If `my colleague and I are not interfere with each other` then `He will encounter conflicts` can not appear at all

**Thoughts**

If you are victim of "Refactoring Hell" (a lot of Tree Conflicts) best method will be to change VCS at least for refactoring stage

You can try to decrease amount of *contextual* conflicts during merges (why they exist?) if you perform cross-branch sync-merges (read `svn help merge`, "The 'Feature Branch' Merging Pattern" part) more often: ideally after each commit to "foreign" branch